# How to connect two different WiFi protocols on same laptop?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ping, 802.11ac

I am trying to run 802.11a and 802.11p WiFi on one laptop using shell scripts. I am getting all connections when I am doing "iwconfig" ( all connections means Wlan0 having 802.11p WiFi and Wlan3 having 802.11a WiFi).

I am using WiFi Dongle for 802.11a and using hardware with external antenna for 802.11p ( 802.11p works absolutely fine even 802.11a script is running)

I can ping devices which are in network of 802.11p but I can not ping devices which are in network of 802.11a.

I am running shell script on linux laptop to make it happen. 
I tried one scenario: I made 802.11a WiFi ON and kept pinging devices in network. all pings were going. and now I ran the 802.11p script, at this point, i got ping message "Destination host unreachable" on 802.11a devices.

is there any drivers issues on the laptop or any conflict which creating this problem. Please guide me in this matter.

Comment: This would require two separate 802.11 adapters.   Do you have the required compatible adapters?

Comment: @Ramhound : if  I am understanding correctly, yes I am using two different USB adapters for both WiFi. For 802.11a, I have a WiFi dongle connected to ubuntu laptop using USB port. For 802.11p, I have a hardware with antenna connected to ubuntu laptop using USB port. Now, I really don't know if you are really talking about these two adapters or two adapters in Ubuntu laptop. I have no idea if i need two 802.11 adapters in ubuntu laptop. Please correct me.